# bind mounts get removed with network namespaces?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, strongswan

Strongswan daemon puts its .pid and .ctl files in /var/run to detect if it is already running.

I want to run multiple of these daemons on the same machine within different network namespaces. I am trying to achieve this by bind mounting different directories (say /etc/namespace1 to namespace1's /var/run and /etc/namespace2 to namespace2's /var/run). /var/run is a symlink to /run, so I bind mount to /run like below.

I can almost achieve this like this:

**""In default namespace""**

```
$:~ sudo echo "red" >> /etc/red/run/pidfile
$:~ sudo echo "blue" >> /etc/blue/run/pidfile
$:~ sudo ip netns exec red
```

**""In red namespace""**

```
$:~ mount --bind /etc/red/run/ /run/
$:~ cat /var/run/pidfile
```

**red**

**""In blue namespace""**

```
 $:~ mount --bind /etc/blue/run/ /run/
 $:~ cat /var/run/pidfile
```

**blue**

So this works fine. This way the daemon when it creates /var/run/charon.pid while inside red will not confuse with blue namespace's /var/run/charon.pid and two instances may start.

However, here's the issue: if I "exit" from red namespace and then re-enter via "ip netns exec red bash", then the mount is no longer present. That is there is no /var/run/redfile at all.

So, the question is how can I make this sticky? Do I need /etc/fstab changes? But it doesn't work. If asked, I can provide details of "it doesn't work".

I am lost. Will appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution would be to instruct each instance of strongswan to use a different directory to store the PID file by means of setting the correct value of the [`IPSEC_PIDDIR`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/strongswan) environment variable in your start and stop script.

Comment: Hi, Certainly that is precisely what I need. But I couldn't find any release that supports passing IPSEC_PIDDIR as an environment variable. I only see it being hardcoded in /usr/sbin/ipsec to be "/var/run". Any pointers/release version would greatly help! I don't see there is any release that honors IPSEC_PIDDIR. Will be very happy if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`ip netns exec` already bind mounts `/etc/netns/<netns name>/*` over the corresponding file/directory in `/etc`. So you may compile strongSwan with e.g. `--with-piddir=/etc/ipsec.d/run` and then create the required directories so each instance creates its PID files in separate directories:

```
# mkdir -p /etc/ipsec.d/run
# mkdir -p /etc/netns/<netns name 1>/ipsec.d/run
# mkdir -p /etc/netns/<netns name 2>/ipsec.d/run
```

More details can be found on the [strongSwan wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Netns#Running-strongSwan-Inside-a-Network-Namespace).

Comment: Hi, Yes I had already tried this approach and it works. But unfortunately for my deployment, I cannot involve the compile step. I will need to work with standard .deb files (I cannot do with compilation changes, autoconf changes or custom .deb files) :(

Answer (score 1):

### Problem cause AFAIK

`ip netns add ${NSNAME}` creates a persistent namespace, by mounting it to `/run/netns/${NSNAME}`.
This in itself does not involve mount namespaces, yet.

Doing `ip netns exec ${NSNAME} cmd` spawns a **temporary** mount namespace that exists until `cmd` exits, after that the mount namespace gets cleaned up, only network namespace remains.
This is required to achieve the magic mounting of `/etc/netns/${NSNAME}/*`.
Unfortunately any mounts done by the `cmd` are cleaned up too.

From `man ip-netns`:

> `ip netns exec` automates handling of this configuration, file convention
> for network namespace unaware applications, by creating a mount name‐
> space and bind mounting all of the per network namespace configure
> files into their traditional location in /etc.

## A solution

### Short version

```bsh
    # Init for persistent mount namespaces
    $ mkdir /run/mntns \
        && mount --bind --make-private /run/mntns /run/mntns

    $ NSNAME=red

    # Create persistent network+mount namespaces
    $ ip netns add ${NSNAME} \
        && touch "/run/mntns/${NSNAME}" \
        && ip netns exec "${NSNAME}" \
            sh -x -c "nsenter -t $$ --mount mount --bind /proc/\$\$/ns/mnt '/run/mntns/${NSNAME}' && :"

    # Do NOT use `ip netns exec`
    # (Re)enter the namespaces with `nsenter`, mounts are persistent
    $ nsenter --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
          program arg1 arg2
```

### Long version

It is possible to create both network and mount namespaces persistent.

This is largely adapted from examples in the `unshare` man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html

The main implication is that instead of `ip netns exec` the `nsenter` must now be used to use both the network+mount namespaces, at least where mounts matter anyway.

## Step 1. Prepare. Create directory for persistent mount namespaces

This needs to be done once, e.g. after boot, NOT for every namespace.
The path here is arbitrary.
I'm trying to use similar naming to that used by `ip netns`.

```bsh
    # Try to create a dir for persistent mount namespaces
    # and if it got created (e.g. first attempt since boot),
    # then bind mount it with --make-private as required by `unshare --mount=/path`
    $ mkdir /run/mntns \
        && mount --bind --make-private /run/mntns /run/mntns
```

Note, the `mkdir ... && mount ...` are not atomic and where there are multiple concurrently starting services doing this sequence then a race condition may occur.

## Step 2. Create network+mount persistent namespaces

### 2a. method A, simple, no magic bind mounts.

This creates persistent mount+network namespaces.
It is simple but does not create magic bind mounts for `/etc/netns/${NSNAME}/*`.

```bsh
    $ NSNAME=red # give it a name

    # For network namespace use same paths as used by `ip netns` for interoperability
    # touch can fail to update timestamp if file is already mounted
    # Try to create files for persistent mounts.
    # and if touch is successful
    # then create persistent mount and network namespaces
    # Instead of `true` can run a command right away e.g. /bin/bash
    # As it is this is approximate equivalent of `ip netns add ${NANAME}`
    $ touch /run/netns/${NSNAME} /run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
        && unshare --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} true
```

### 2b. method B, leverage `ip netns exec` to make mounts but make persistent.

To get those bind mount done by `ip netns exec ...` but make them persistent, can do setup as follows.
Note this must be done once ONLY when creating the namespace, not every time.

```bsh
    $ ip netns add ${NSNAME} \
        && touch "/run/mntns/${NSNAME}" \
        && ip netns exec "${NSNAME}" \
            sh -x -c "nsenter -t $$ --mount mount --bind /proc/\$\$/ns/mnt '/run/mntns/${NSNAME}' && :"
```

For an attempted explanation see towards the end.

## Steps 3. Use it

Now the `nsenter` must be used to launch commands inside both the namespaces as required to achieve persistent mount results.
This is regardless if setup was done with `unshare` or `ip netns exec NAME sh ... nsneter ... mount ...`.

```bsh
    # Get a shell inside the namespaces
    $ nsenter --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
        /bin/bash
```

e.g. with OP's commands:

```bsh
    # Do your additional mounts (can also be done above as command to `unshare`)
    # This is approximate equivalent of 
    #   `ip netns exec ${NANAME} mount --bind /etc/red/run/ /run/`
    $ nsenter --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
          mount --bind /etc/${NSNAME}/run/ /run/

    # Re-enter the namespaces, check that the mounts are still there
    $ nsenter --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
          sh -c 'ls /run/'
```

**Important**

This approach works, but instead of using `ip netns exec` use `nsenter --net=... --mount=...`!
If `ip netns exec ...` is used it will replace (for the duration of its run) the mount namespace, which can be ok for commands that do not care about mount's persistence, e.g.

```bsh
    # This does not touch any files, only operates on network device
    ip netns exec ${NSNAME} ip link set up dev lo
```

## Step Z. - Clean up

Regardless which of the two methods above was used to create the namespaces, the clean up can be done by either of the two methods:

```bsh
    # This deletes the /mnt/netns/${NSNAME} for us
    ip netns del ${NSNAME}
    # Unmount and delete mount namespace holder
    umount "/mnt/mntns/${NSNAME}" \
        && rm "/mnt/mntns/${NSNAME}"
```

or

```bsh
    # Unmount and delete both namespaces' holders
    umount "/mnt/mntns/${NSNAME}" "/mnt/netns/${NSNAME}" \
        && rm "/mnt/mntns/${NSNAME}" "/mnt/netns/${NSNAME}"
```

## Explanation

Apologies for long text. This is in part for my own benefit.

This command from step **2b** above deserves some explanation.

The command again.

```bsh
    $ ip netns add ${NSNAME} \
        && touch "/run/mntns/${NSNAME}" \
        && ip netns exec "${NSNAME}" \
            sh -x -c "nsenter -t $$ --mount mount --bind /proc/\$\$/ns/mnt '/run/mntns/${NSNAME}' && :"
```

From `man unshare`

> The  namespaces  can  optionally  be  made  persistent by bind mounting
> /proc/pid/ns/type  files  to  a  filesystem  path  and   entered   with
> nsenter(1)  even  after  the  program terminates (except PID namespaces
> where permanently running init process is required).  Once a persistent
> namespace  is  no  longer needed, it can be unpersisted with umount(8).

**Explanation start**

Here is what it does, if broken down into simple steps.
Note, two shells are required for this demo.

```bsh
    # SHELL-1

    # Init
    $ mkdir /run/mntns \
        && mount --bind --make-private /run/mntns /run/mntns

    # Prep
    $ NSNAME=red

    # Create namespace
    $ ip netns add ${NSNAME}
    # Start a shell inside the namespace
    $ ip netns exec "${NSNAME}" /bin/bash

    # Now inside a shell inside a namespace.
    # Now need to make a bind mount it this shell's mount namespace
    $ echo $$ # Use this in SHELL2 AS SHELL1_PID
    # Go to SHELL-2 before exiting this one
```

```bsh
    # SHELL-2

    # Set this to PID from SHELL-1
    $ SHELL1_PID=????

    $ NSNAME=red
    $ touch "/run/mntns/${NSNAME}"

    $ mount --bind /proc/${SHELL1_PID}/ns/mnt "/run/mntns/${NSNAME}"
```

Now both network+mount namespaces are persistent and can be re-entered with `nsenter` as shown way earlier.

The important part is mounting `ip netns exec`'s `/proc/pid/ns/net` into the outer shell's mount namespace **before** `ip netns exec..`  exits.

**Explanation cont.**

So the answer is: from within `ip netns exec ...` do `nsenter`, but not as a direct command <strike>`ip netns exec ${NSNAME} nsenter ...`</strike>, because that would `exec()` without `fork()` therefore leave and destroy the temporary namespace, but rather cause a fork() by running an intermediate shell that keeps the temporary namespace active, and the forked `nsenter` does `mount`.
This following is closer to how the one long command works.

```bsh
    # Init
    $ mkdir /run/mntns \
        && mount --bind --make-private /run/mntns /run/mntns

    # Prep
    $ export NSNAME=red
    $ touch "/run/mntns/${NSNAME}"

    $ export MOUNT_PARENT_PID=$$ # for simplicity

    # Create namespace
    $ ip netns add ${NSNAME}
    # Start a shell inside the namespace, the intermediate shell is important
    $ ip netns exec "${NSNAME}" /bin/bash
    # Now inside a forked namespaced shell

    # Need to mount `ip netns exec` temporary mount namespace to a file
    # within MOUNT_PARENT_PID's namespace to make it persistent
    # nsenter will reference it later

    $$ nsenter -t ${MOUNT_PARENT_PID} --mount \
           mount --bind /proc/$$/ns/mnt "/run/mntns/${NSNAME}"

    # Yes, here $MOUNT_PARENT_PID can be replaced by $PPID
    # But if any intermediate sub-shells and forks get introduced
    # then $PPID can point to a different process.
```

It seems some versions of `bash` invoked with `-c command` for a single command optimise out the `fork()` and that fork() is really needed here, so force it to fork() with `&& :` at the end of the command (See short version at the start).

## Manually mounting `/etc/netns/${NSNAME}/*`

The original answer had this section, so here it is, although likely not very useful.

**Re-Creating /mnt/netns/${NSNAME}/* bind mounts**

The downside of using `unshare` is you don't get the automatic bind mounting of `/etc/netns/NETNS_NAME/*` that is provided by `ip netns exec ${NSNAME} cmd`, which is not hard to add manually.

```bsh
    # either during unshare or later as nsenter.
    # The important difference is here it is done once and result persists
    # unlike with `ip netns exec` which does this every time
    NSNAME="${NSNAME}" \
      nsenter --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
      /bin/sh -e -x -c \
      'cd "/etc/netns/${NSNAME}"; for f in *; do mount --bind "/etc/netns/${NSNAME}/${f}" "/etc/${f}"; done;'
```

Comment: You're right, I just noticed the ns bind mount failing and came to a wrong conclusion.