# ifup, ifdown get interface state wrong when using network namespaces, in Ubuntu and Raspbian

Tags: linux, networking, network-namespaces

I create several network namespaces with `ip netns add ns1`, `ip netns add ns2`.

When I try to start/stop network interfaces inside network namespaces with `ifup` and `ifdown` the interface state is wrong:

```
$ ifup lo
ifup: interface lo already configured
```

I believe this is because the /run/network/ is where `ifup` and `ifdown` keep the state and it is shared between default and additional network namespaces when created as above. I think so because when I create veth interfaces inside a network namespace, the corresponding entries turn up in main space in /run/network. This problem applies to `lo` interface as well.

I'm seeing same problem in Ubuntu-12-LTS and 2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-lite. I have a vague memory dealing with similar symptoms in `CentOS-7.4` a while back just not investigating it for causes.

To demonstrate (on Raspbian) I create and ifup/ifdown a bridge inside each network namespace, and check content of /run/network/ in the default space.

Setup

```
$ echo 'iface br2 inet manual' > /etc/network/interfaces.d/br2

$ ip netns add ns1
$ ip netns add ns2
$ ip netns exec ns1 ip link add br2 type bridge
$ ip netns exec ns2 ip link add br2 type bridge
```

Check that `br2` state does not exists

```
$ cat /run/network/ifstate.br2
cat: /run/network/ifstate.br2: No such file or directory
```

Good, the `br2` has not been `ifup`ed of `ifdown`ed ever in any namespace.
Bring up/down/up the interface on 1st namespace

```
$ ip netns exec ns1 ifup br2
$ cat /run/network/ifstate.br2
br2
$ ip netns exec ns1 ifdown br2
$ cat /run/network/ifstate.br2

$ ip netns exec ns1 ifup br2
$ cat /run/network/ifstate.br2
br2
```

OK, and now do same up/down/up on 2nd namespace, causes error

```
$ ip netns exec ns2 ifup br2
ifup: interface br2 already configured

$ cat /run/network/ifstate.br2
br2
```

This above is the problem!
Stop the interface via 2nd namespace (note it was started via 1st)

```
$ ip netns exec ns2 ifdown br2
$ cat /run/network/ifstate.br2
```

Now back to 1st namespace

```
$ ip netns exec ns1 ifdown br2
ifdown: interface br2 not configured
$ cat /run/network/ifstate.br2
```

Above is similar problem, interface wad stopped in 2nd namespace, but is reported as down in 1st.

Unfortunately this applies to `lo` so it's impossible to avoid it by simply having unique names inside each namespace. I just have to keep cycling interfaces with 'up/down/up' to get around this issue. I hope there is a cleaner way to do this.

**My use case and goals:** I create multiple identical namespaces similar to test above only wrapped into systemd instanced service units, start their interfaces (having to up/down/up to work around the issue). At various times I launch programs inside each namespace, with `ip netns exec nsX prog args` often also by other systemd services. Some time later I dismantle certain namespace, and I need to do this carefully. I need `ifdown` to do its work properly as it tidies things up. The networks are non-trivial, with several `veth` interfaces, bridges and associate `iptables` and `sysctl` settings, so I really want `ifup` and `ifdown` to work well and not get confused by other namespace's state. E.g. `ifdown` removes `veth` interfaces. Certainly workaround are possible, but it gets hacky/dirty quickly.

I feel like I need to mount tmpfs onto `/run/network` within network namespace somehow, but I don't know how. The `ip netns exec` bind mounts few things only for duration of the program that runs, not permanently attached to the network namespace itself, it seems. If I bind mount during setup invocation `ip netns exec ns1 ifup ...` it will exit and not be available later when I need to do `.... ifdown`.

I am open to different methods of creating network namespaces. I just need some way of tracking things so I can launch several programs in the right namespace at different points in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ip netns add` creates a persistent network namespace only, and `ip netns exec ...` enters a persistent network namespace while also creating a temporary mount namespace. There is another question that asks directly about this problem, so I answered it in more detail there. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581618/142686

My solution is to create both network and mount namespaces persistent by using `unshare`.
Then mount `tmpfs` over `/run/network` inside the namespace.
This gives the namespace a separate copy for `ifup` and `ifdown` to use.

The main implication is that instead of `ip netns exec` the `nsenter` must now be used, at least where mounts matter anyway.

**Create directory for persistent mount namespaces**

This needs to be done once after boot, NOT for every namespace

```
# Create a dir for persistent mount namespaces
$ mkdir /run/mntns

# Bind mount it with --make-private as required by `unshare --mount=/path`
$ mount --bind --make-private /run/mntns /run/mntns
```

**Create network+mount persistent namespaces**

```
$ NSNAME=testns # give it a name

# Create files for persistent mounts.
# For network namespace use same paths as used by `ip netns` for interoperability
$ touch /run/netns/${NSNAME} /run/mntns/${NSNAME}

# Create persistent mount and network namespaces and
# as part of the setup the command (inside the namespace) adds a mount.
$ unshare --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
    mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /run/network
```

**Use it**

```
# Bring up the loopback interface, this used to fail.
$ nsenter --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
    ifup lo
# Good.
```

**More testing**

The important part now.
Moving network interfaces into the namespace.
Here using `ip` is fine.

```
# Plug a veth interface into the namespace, use the `ip netns link`
$ ip link add veth1a type veth peer name veth1b netns ${NSNAME}

# Verify it is there (although here `ip netns exec` would work just as well)
$ nsenter --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
    ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: veth1b@if17: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:1b:ea:e5:77:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

**Important**

This approach works, but instead of using `ip netns exec` use `nsenter --net=... --mount=...`!

In order to move the interfaces between namespaces using the 'ip link' still works.

The downside is you don't get the automatic bind mounting of `/etc/netns/NETNS_NAME/*` that is provided by `ip netns exec NETNS_NAME cmd`, which is not hard to add manually.

```
# either during unshare or later as nsenter.
# The important difference is here it is done once and result persists
# unlike with `ip netns exec` which does this every time
NSNAME="${NSNAME}" \
  nsenter --net=/run/netns/${NSNAME} --mount=/run/mntns/${NSNAME} \
  /bin/sh -e -x -c \
  'cd "/etc/netns/${NSNAME}"; for f in *; do mount --bind "/etc/netns/${NSNAME}/${f}" "/etc/${f}"; done;'
```

The upside is you get consistent mounts done once, and not on every `ip netns exec` which can vary if the content of `/etc/netns/NETNS_NAME/` changes between invocations.